# Visualforce Event page Standard hour picker and duration fields

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, event

I want to add in my visualforce the hour picker and the duration standard fields

This is the target:

[image]

Now I have this in my visualforce page:

[image]

There is a way to put the same fields maybe using jquery something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of using the standard controls for this. Like you suggest you'll have to implement this manually (unless you can find it pre-built somewhere, but I've not seen a solution using duration).

You don't necessarily need to use jQuery for this though, you could just use `<apex:selectList>` elements to do the input for hours and minutes, capturing the values into public variables and then doing the logic in the controller.